# Can not data bind to table using knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

```js
//AJAX Webservice Call
ManualRegDiseaseData = $.parseJSON(rows.d);
        var VM = new testView(ManualRegDiseaseData);
        ko.applyBindings(VM);

var testView = function (DiseaseData) {

    var self = this;
    self.disease = ko.observableArray();
    self.benefitData = ko.observableArray();

    var sampleBenefit = [{ "Benefit": "Room", "Detail": "Ordinary", "Desc": "not herbal", "TotalDays": "2", "Remaining": "1000", "Claimed": "400", "Approved": "350", "Excess": "50" },
               { "Benefit": "Medicine", "Detail": "All", "Desc": "herbal", "TotalDays": "1", "Remaining": "2000", "Claimed": "800", "Approved": "600", "Excess": "100" }];
    $.each(sampleBenefit, function (x, rowType) {
        var obj = new BenefitObject();
        obj.Benefit(rowType.Benefit);
        obj.Detail(rowType.Detail);
        obj.Desc(rowType.Desc);
        obj.TotalDays(rowType.TotalDays);
        obj.Remaining(rowType.Remaining);
        obj.Claimed(rowType.Claimed);
        obj.Approved(rowType.Approved);
        obj.Excess(rowType.Excess);
        self.benefitData.push(obj);
    })

    $.each(DiseaseData, function (x, rowType) {
        var obj = new DiseaseObject();
        obj.DiseaseCode(rowType.DiseaseCode);
        obj.DiseaseName(rowType.DiseaseName);
        self.disease.push(obj);
    })

}
```

```html
 <table id="tblDisplayBenefit" class="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Benefit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Detail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Description&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Total Days&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Remaining Inner Limit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Claimed&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Approved&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Excess&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Reduce Max Limit </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: benefitData">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="value: Benefit"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: Detail"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: Desc"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: TotalDays"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: Remaining"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: Claimed"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: Approved"></td>
            <td data-bind="value: Excess"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" style="text-align: right">Total</td>
            <td>Total Claimed</td>
            <td>Total Approved</td>
            <td>Total Excess</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Those are my JS snippet code and my html, the problem is, I can not data bind the sample JSON variable into my table. It seems I can not push my data into benefitData object.
I have been doing console.log the rowType, the Json data is readable through the console.log.

I dont know, this must be a simple data binding, yet I dont know where is the fault part.
I cant figure this out.

Thanks in advance for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text` binding instead of `value` for text int the table cells:

```
<td data-bind="text: Benefit"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Detail"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Desc"></td>
<td data-bind="text: TotalDays"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Remaining"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Claimed"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Approved"></td>
<td data-bind="text: Excess"></td>
```

**[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0nhpkca/)**

According to [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)

> The value binding links the associated DOM element’s value with a
>   property on your view model. This is typically useful with form
>   elements such as **input**, **select** and **textarea**.

In other words it works with form elements and makes two-way binding, so when you change the value knockout automatically updates your ViewModel.

On the other hand, [text binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)

> Typically this is useful with elements like **span** or **em** that
>   traditionally display text, but technically you can use it with any
>   element.

So you should use `text` binding here, because `<td>` element has static content.

Comment: really works! I dont know what terms should using text and value. Would you mind to explain?